# Python Requests POST url encoded request not working

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I am trying to make a post request to a url with Requests in Python. I am getting 500 ERROR message. I think the problem is in not properly encoding in content-type to x-www-form-urlencoded. If I try the same request in Postman it is working.

My Python code:

```
import requests


def get_pdf_link_by_post(url, payload):
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    print requests
    print "**************Headers*******************"
    print r.headers
    print r.content

def process_kat_causelist(date, adv_name):
    url = 'http://kat.kar.nic.in:8080/causelistsearch.jsp'
    for court_hall_idx in range(1, 4):
        court_hall = str(court_hall_idx)+'~Court Hall '+str(court_hall_idx)
        for list_idx in range(1, 7):
            list_num = str(list_idx)+'~List '+str(list_idx)
            payload = {'firstClDate': date, 'secondCldate': date, 'courthall': court_hall, 'lists': list_num}
            print payload
            get_pdf_link_by_post(url, payload)


process_kat_causelist('25/08/2015', 'ani')
```

Postman request:

[image]

Comment: From the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.7/user/quickstart/#make-a-post-request) it looks like the way you're do it is right. I've [read](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html) this about the HTTP Error 500 Internal server error: "This error can only be resolved by fixes to the Web server software. It is not a client-side problem. It is up to the operators of the Web server site to locate and analyse the logs which should give further information about the error."

Comment: If it is a server side problem why does it work in Postman ?

Comment: Your example code works for me (I just installed `requests` a few days ago). Perhaps you have an old version.

Comment: Works as in ? Do you see a pdf link in the returned response ? What response do you get ?

Comment: I misspoke, it is getting the 500 - Server Error, as can bee seen [here](http://pastebin.com/vcWZ21zi). It says "There is a temporary error on the server. Please inform the administrator".

Comment: Ya, if you are curious try Postman Rest Client Chrome app. It gives the correct result. I am curious what is the App doing right which my Python script isn't doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the payload  secondCldate must be secondClDate